# Toggle Scroll Lock on or off

Tags: powershell, keyboard, scroll-lock

I am using PowerShell in my script to check the status of various keys like <kbd>NumLock</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

```
powershell.exe -Command [Console]::CapsLock
powershell.exe -Command [Console]::NumberLock
```

But I found no way to check the status of <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> through PowerShell console command. Can you guys tell me why `powershell.exe -Command [Console]::ScrollLock` does not work and what is needed to be done?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `ScrollLock` key state with the [`GetKeyState()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) from the `user32.dll` native Windows API:

```
Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);
'@ -Name keyboardfuncs -Namespace user32

# 0x91 = 145, the virtual key code for the Scroll Lock key 
# see http://www.foreui.com/articles/Key_Code_Table.htm
if([user32.keyboardfuncs]::GetKeyState(0x91) -eq 0){
    # Scroll Lock is off
}
else {
    # Scroll Lock is on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it by running:

`[System.Windows.Forms.Control]::IsKeyLocked('Scroll')`

Comment: NOTE: This only works if you run `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` first!